# Sharepoint List data with Power Bi

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerbi

I am trying to generate a report on a Sharepoint List with Power Bi. The list is a custom made list solely used for users to raise tickets

With Power Bi, I am able to pull the Sharepoint List Data however the data that i got is not very user friendly. Instead on a user's display name I get IDs. Is that normal? i have attached the Fields that Power Bi got from my helpdesk list

Some of these Field items are foreign to me as well

[image]

Comment: nevermind guys, i managed to find a tutorial for this. Looks like i have to connect 2 tables and create a relationship between them. Link for anyone looking for the same thing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=ugoHcHSY8lg

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Edit Queries" on the home tab. This is the data scrubbing and transforming layer.

[image]

For the "junk" columns:
These are metadata fields in the list, that could be useful at some point. For now they are a nuisance, so,
Delete the columns you do not recognize or use. (You can always retrieve a column you deleted by editing the query steps on the right).

As for the missing Display Names:
Get those by "expanding" the UserID column. It will be named something reminiscent of the column name for the Person/Group field in your list. There will be a double arrow icon in the header like this:

[image]

Click it, and select the field "Display Name" and the names should show up in a new column.

Hit Close & Apply.